# Bogoliubov transformation BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, superconductivity, many-body, mean-field-theory

I am reading on the BCS theory and the bogoliubov transformation to diagonilize the BCS Hamiltonian. And there is one step that I really can't seem to get.

So the Hamiltonian looks like this:

\begin{equation}H=\sum_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} \xi_{\mathbf{k}} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}-\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(\Delta_{\mathbf{k}} c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}+\Delta_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow} c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}\right)+\sum_{\mathbf{k}} \Delta_{\mathbf{k}}\left\langle c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\right\rangle\end{equation}

And then we define the operators
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow} &=u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}+v_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} \\
c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} &=u_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}-v_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

and they have the normalization condition: \begin{equation}\left|u_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}+\left|v_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}=1\end{equation}

So that the first term becomes:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} \xi_{\mathbf{k}} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} &=\sum_{\mathbf{k}} \xi_{\mathbf{k}}\left[c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}+c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} c_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\right] \\
&=\sum_{\mathbf{k}} \xi_{\mathbf{k}}\left[\left(\left|u_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}-\left|v_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}\right)\left(\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}+\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\right)+2\left|v_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}+2 u_{\mathbf{k}} v_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}+2 u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} v_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}\right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

It is the last step I don't understand, when I put the operators into the hamiltonian I get something like this:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow} &=\left(u_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger}+v_{-\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\right) \left(u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}+v_{\mathbf{k}}\gamma_{\mathbf{-k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\right)\\
&=|u_{\mathbf{k}}|^2\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger}\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow} + u_{\mathbf{k}} v_{\mathbf{k}}\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} \gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} + u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} v_{\mathbf{k}}^{*}\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \uparrow} +|v_{\mathbf{k}}|^2\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\\
c_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger} c_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow} &=\left(-v_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{-k} \uparrow}+u_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\right) \left(-v_{\mathbf{k}} \gamma_{\mathbf{-k} \uparrow}^{\dagger}+u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*}\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}\right)\\
&=|v_{\mathbf{k}}|^2\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \uparrow} \gamma_{\mathbf{-k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} - u_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} v_{\mathbf{k}}^{*} \gamma_{\mathbf{-k} \uparrow} \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow} - u_{\mathbf{k}} v_{\mathbf{k}}\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\gamma_{-\mathbf{k} \uparrow}^{\dagger} +|u_{\mathbf{k}}|^2 \gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}^{\dagger}\gamma_{\mathbf{k} \downarrow}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

I really don't see how adding these terms together forms the equation that is above. Especially the $2\left|v_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}$ term confuses me how it is supposed to be there, with no operator terms, my guess is that the operators cancel out somehow but I don't see it.
Maybe I did something wrong above or am missing something crucial. I could really use a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the Bogoliubov transformation to be canonical, so it must preserve the canonical anticommutation relations. That is, you need $\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}\delta_{\sigma\sigma'}=\{\gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}, \gamma_{\mathbf{k}'\sigma'}^\dagger\}$. In particular this implies $\gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}\gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^\dagger = 1 - \gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^\dagger \gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}$. The constant gives you the $2|v_\mathbf{k}|^2$ term.